# How to use multiple variables in a mixed model?

Tags: r, mixed-model, experiment-design

This is a follow up question to [How to model this mixed model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/441573/how-to-model-this-mixed-model/443812?noredirect=1#comment827386_443812)
There, I asked how to model `Resistance` against `carbon monoxide` for a pool of sensors from three different manufacturers. Random effects are the sensors in dependency of the gas.
The measurements were taken to get a basic relationship. Now, I've added more variables like humidity, temperature and two other gases ethen and hydrogen.

I want to fully investigate the sensors due to all influences. Therefore, I thought I could get started with the formula description from the previous question:

```r
lmer( log_R ~ log_c + Manufacturer + log_c:Manufacturer + 
              ( log_c | Sensor), data = d)
```

and just begin to add some more features:

```r
lmer( log_R ~ log_c + Manufacturer + humidity + temperature + 
              log_c:Manufacturer + ( log_c | Sensor), data = d)
```

In the very first instance, I'm facing an issue that I cannot allocate a vector of 118.2 Gb. Hence, I've the following question:

How can I find out which variables are significant? And how do I add those to the formula above?
Only as main effects? Or as interaction effects as well?

**edit**: The measurements:

```r
    Temperature [°C] Rel. Humidity [%]  Hydrogen [ppm]  Carbon_monoxide [ppm]   Ethen[ppm]
50  30  250 250 50
18  11  100 100 100
18  11  500 500 100
18  11  100 500 25
18  11  500 100 25
70  11  100 500 100
70  11  500 500 25
70  11  100 100 25
70  11  500 100 100
50  30  250 250 50
18  84  500 100 100
18  84  100 500 100
18  84  100 100 25
18  84  500 500 25
70  84  500 500 100
70  84  100 100 100
70  84  100 500 25
70  84  500 100 25
50  30  250 250 50
```

and my current **model**:

```r
lmer( log10(Resistance) 
                  ##### Resolution V
                  ### Fixed effects
                  
                  # main effects (not confound with each other)
                  ~ log10(Carbon_monoxide) + 
                  Manufacturer +
                  rH +
                  Temperature +
                  Ethen +
                  Hydrogen +                      
                  # two-factor interactions aliased with each 
                  # other (main effects are not confound with)
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide) +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen +
                  Manufacturer:Ethen +
                  Manufacturer:rH +
                  Manufacturer:Temperature +                    
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):rH +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Temperature +                    
                  Hydrogen:Ethen +
                  Hydrogen:rH +
                  Hydrogen:Temperature +                    
                  Ethen:rH +
                  Ethen:Temperature +                    
                  # three-factor interactions
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen +
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen +
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):rH +
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:Ethen +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:rH +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:Ethen:rH +
                  Manufacturer:Ethen:Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:rH:Temperature +                        
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:rH +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Temperature +                        
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen:rH +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):rH:Temperature +
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen:Temperature +                        
                  Hydrogen:Ethen:rH +
                  Hydrogen:rH:Temperature +
                  Hydrogen:Ethen:Temperature +                        
                  Ethen:rH:Temperature +                      
                  # four-factor interactions                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen +
            Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:rH +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:Ethen:rH +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:rH:Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:Ethen:rH:Temperature +                        
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:rH +                       log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:Temperature +                        
                  Hydrogen:Ethen:rH:Temperature +                        
                  Manufacturer:Ethen:rH:Temperature +
                  Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen:rH +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen:Temperature +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):rH:Temperature +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:Ethen:Temperature +                      
                  log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:rH:Temperature +                      
                  # five-factor interactions                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:rH +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:Temperature +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:rH:Temperature +                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Ethen:rH:Temperature +
                  Manufacturer:Hydrogen:Ethen:rH:Temperature +                      log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:rH:Temperature +                        
                  # six-factor interactions                      Manufacturer:log10(Carbon_monoxide):Hydrogen:Ethen:rH:Temperature                      
                  ### random effects
                 # ( log10(Carbon_monoxide) | Manufacturer)
                  , data = data)
```

**data**: https://www.file-upload.net/download-13853720/data.csv.html

`data` consists of 380 observations in total with 20 sensors. 5 sensors are from Manufacturer A, 5 from B and 10 from C.

I took the interactions from https://learnche.org/pid/design-analysis-experiments/fractional-factorial-designs/design-resolution (hopefully I understood it correctly).
I'm not quite sure how to determine the random effects..
The most important variables are `Resistance` against `Carbon_monoxide` as this my target gas. The other gases are just to check whether they affect the measurement.

edit: To get started, I wanted to perform a linear model first and compare it afterwards with the mixed model. Therefore, I used the above model description and removed the random effect. Then, I get this plot:

[image: Plot]

I wonder whether this makes sense. On the one hand I expected a fit for each sensor, on the other hand when I fit separately, how can I make use out of the `Manufacturer` or `Sensor` variable?
Do they only play a role in case of a mixed model?

For a `lm()`-model, do I have to use e.g. `lmList()`?

Comment: I suspect *Manufacturer* should be a random effect.

Comment: How many observations are in your data frame that are leading to a vector size of 118.2Gb? If you have that much data, you probably need to be working on a supercomputer.

Comment: It's quite few data..  only about 19 * 20 data points with above number of variables.. but I have to add that I can fit it, the problem occurs when using "expand.grid".

Comment: @Roland unless this is a different dataset, there are only 3 manufacturers.

Comment: You have run out of memory. Does this also happen if you start an empty R session, load the data and then run the model ?

Comment: Yes, but meanwhile I think it isn't that important. At the very moment I'm fine with applying a proper model so I can check which variables are significant. Will add my current model and further information.

Comment: When I remove the random effects and run only a lm() I receive no warning.

Comment: Without seeing the raw data it is difficult to be sure, but at least one problem is that you are fitting random intercepts for `Manufacturer` and also fixed effects for it. What happens when you remove it from the fixed part ?

Comment: Right, I removed it. Now I get the same but with the following added to it: "4: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  unable to evaluate scaled gradient
5: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
  Model failed to converge: degenerate  Hessian with 1 negative eigenvalues"
And I added the data.

Comment: Ok, then take  Manufacturer out of the random part - you still only have 3 right ?

Comment: Also I'm not sure it makes sense to have random slopes for Carbon_monoxide since you also fit 2 and 3 way interactions for it. I would either remove it as a random slope or include the interactions as random slopes (the latter may not be supported by the data)

Comment: Yes, only 3. Ok, will try it out. Is it possible to find out whether the model improves when using a lmer() instead of lm()?

Comment: I added a plot for the lm() model. Could you please check? I wonder whether this makes sense at all.. The $R^2$-value is $0.97$